# Socket.IO connects but is not emitting

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, deployment, socket.io, mern

To prefice this is a MERN socket.io application unfortunately I can't share my source since it's also connected to my aws account.

When on localhost my entire app works perfectly, however when deploying to AWS the back end fails. There are no errors, and when looking at the network it does show up with a successful link to socket.io. I've changed and updated the server for nginx so that it doesn't give off a bad gateway error. However after doing this there is no other error, I just can't register or login, client side validation seems to work however back end validation does not. If you'd like to take a look it's currently on http://3.145.119.85/

I currently connect to socket.io like so

```
const [socket] = useState(() => io(":8000"));
```

My server side instantiating

```
> const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

require("./components/mongoose.config");

app.use(cors());
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(express.json(), express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("listening at port " + PORT));
require("./components/puzzleio.sockets") (server);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have changed the host address from `localhost` to the real aws address. It seemed natural that `socket.io` should connect to the root from where you serve your content.

Since you are using AWS and after each restart you get different DNS address you have sent to the page where you are initializing the `socket.io` then correct the `req.headers.host` (using `express-expose`).